# USB flash drive appears only in lsusb

Tags: usb, remote-access

I have a 64GB USB 3.0 flash drive that is not detected automatically. It only appears in the output of the `lsusb` command.

```
Bus 004 Device 009: ID 1f75:0917 Innostor Technology Corporation
```

The output of `dmesg`:

```
usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[12196.233216] scsi host9: usb-storage 4-2:1.0
[12217.986180] usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 8    using          xhci_hcd
[18587.882254] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 8
[28646.482672] usb 4-1.3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[28646.497517] usb 4-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0917
[28646.497520] usb 4-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[28646.497522] usb 4-1.3: Product: USB DISK
[28646.497525] usb 4-1.3: Manufacturer:  
[28646.497528] usb 4-1.3: SerialNumber: 15081333000027
[28646.499445] usb-storage 4-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[28646.499516] scsi host10: usb-storage 4-1.3:1.0
[28668.551570] usb 4-1.3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using   xhci_hcd
```

As you can see, no device is assigned.

Is there any possibility to get access to this USB or, if it is corrupted, to repair it?

All of the tools that I found require access to the USB.

Comment: Please add the output of `lsblk`.

Answer (score 1):

USB 3 devices are sometimes tricky, and do not work with some combinations of operating system and computer hardware. So it is a good idea to try in different USB ports and in different computers, if possible also with Windows or MacOS.

The tools that I know, need to see a USB pendrive as a mass storage device (typically **/dev/sdx**), where x is the drive letter **a** or **b** ...
You can search for the drive with the following commands

```
sudo lsblk -f
sudo lsblk -m
```

But it is ***not*** necessary to be able to mount it (and see the file system) in order to repair it. You can try to wipe the first megabyte with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). See the following links

[pendrive lifetime](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297)

[how to repair a pendrive](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)

If wiping the first megabyte does not work in any USB port of at least two different computers, it is probably damaged beyond repair.